# SQLalchemy русские символы

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка, sqlalchemy

Мне нужно вставить/найти/сделать что-то *русские символы (кириллицу)* еще в SQLalchemy. Есть следующий код:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
# получение сессии бд
engine = create_engine('postgresql://юзер@localhost:5432/база',
                       pool_size=100,
                       max_overflow=10,
                       echo=True,
                       convert_unicode=True)


@contextmanager
def session():
    connection = engine.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=True, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    try:
        yield db_session
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        db_session.remove()
        connection.close()
with session() as s:
    s.execute("insert into imgs values(DEFAULT, 1, 'уцва', 'выа')")
```

В этом коде происходит ошибка:

```
2018-06-01 00:31:21,870 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into imgs values(DEFAULT, 1, 'уцва', 'выа')
2018-06-01 00:31:21,870 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-06-01 00:31:21,871 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 37-40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Как я могу исправить это?

Answer (score 1):

Решение просто. Всё, что описано в ответах выше, не подходит - там варианты для MySQL, а у меня Postgresql. Мне нужно было добавить параметр `client_encoding='utf8'` в create_engine()

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы данные были преобразованы автоматически, вы должны указать кодировку при создании движка:

```
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb:///mydb?charset=utf8')
```

Comment: Это **лучший из вариантов**, но предлагают еще каждую строку декодировать.

_PS: надо учится гуглить на [английской стороне stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819192/sqlalchemy-result-for-utf-8-column-is-of-type-str-why)_

Comment: Я виноват, не указал, что бд это Postgresql. Там не работает параметр charset

Comment: В таком случае, что говорит команда `SHOW client_encoding;`?  PS: сам не заметил..

Comment: @Dmytry-Hoi я уже решил проблему и написал решение. Спасибо