# Кириллические буквы записываются в базу как коды символов юникода

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

В базе есть колонка типа JSON, вот строчка, которая её задаёт: `content = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.JSON)`. Когда записываю туда словарь через sqlalchemy, все буквы кириллицы заменяются на u2392 и подобные коды. Если сделать прямой запрос без sqlalchemy `INSERT INTO...`, то кириллица запишется нормально и будет отображаться нормально. В чём проблема?

Comment: *В чём проблема?* Есссно в sqlalchemy...

Answer (score 0):

В `create_engine` попробуйте добавить аргумент `client_encoding='utf8'`.

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836152/sqlalchemy-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Comment: Вряд ли это имеет какое-то отношение к кодированию JSON